# How to show pop up the pdf file instead of saving internally using java?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, itext

I have used iText jar to export the contents in pdf. I have used FileOutputStream to store the file in my local (like D:/filename.pdf). Instead of doing this, I need to show the popup dialog box to be appear and ask for save option in pdf. How to achieve it?

```
Here is my code.

JSP:

<%@ page language="java" 
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Export to Excel - Demo</title>
<!-- Jquery script -->
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<script language="javascript"> 
function ExportToPDF()
{

    $('#myForm').submit();      
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="Sample" method="post">
    <br><br>
    <p>
    some text
    </p>
    <a href="" onclick="ExportToPDF();" target="_blank">Export to Excel</a>

   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;



/**
 * Servlet implementation class Sample
 */
public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Sample() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside doGet");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Inside doPost");
        try {
            actionExportToPDF(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

  public void actionExportToPDF(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
  {

      /* Create Connection objects */
      Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); 
      Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XID","username","password");
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      System.out.println(conn);
      /* Define the SQL query */
      ResultSet query_set = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT first_name,last_name,email,phone,dob,squestion FROM signup");
      /* Step-2: Initialize PDF documents - logical objects */
      Document my_pdf_report = new Document();
      PdfWriter.getInstance(my_pdf_report, new FileOutputStream("D:/pdf_report_from_sql_using_java.pdf"));
      my_pdf_report.open();            
      //we have four columns in our table
      PdfPTable my_report_table = new PdfPTable(4);
      //create a cell object
      PdfPCell table_cell;

      while (query_set.next()) {                
                      String first_id = query_set.getString("first_name");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(first_id));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      String last_name=query_set.getString("last_name");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(last_name));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      String email_id=query_set.getString("email");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(email_id));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      String phone_id=query_set.getString("phone");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(phone_id));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      String dob_id=query_set.getString("dob");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dob_id));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      String squestion_id=query_set.getString("squestion");
                      table_cell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(squestion_id));
                      my_report_table.addCell(table_cell);
                      }
      /* Attach report table to PDF */
      my_pdf_report.add(my_report_table);                       
      my_pdf_report.close();

      /* Close all DB related objects */
      query_set.close();
      stmt.close(); 
      conn.close();     


  }

}
```

Used Jars:

itextpdf-5.2.0.jar

itextpdf-5.2.0-javadoc.jar

itextpdf-5.2.0-sources.jar

itext-xtra-5.2.0.jar

itext-xtra-5.2.0-javadoc.jar

itext-xtra-5.2.0-sources.jar

ojdbc14-10g.jar

Comment: just note that in the most browsers popups are disabled by default. And end-users, who are not familiar with such issues may experience problems with your popup pdf file.

Comment: **Important:** there are *serious technical problems* with iText 5.2. We have removed all these versions from our servers. See http://itextpdf.com/changelog/52 **YOU REALLY NEED TO UPGRADE!!!** Contact us for more info: http://itextpdf.com/contact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `PdfWriter` can write PDF to any `OutputStream`. If you want to create a Servlet, you shouldn't write PDF to a `FileOutputStream`, but to a `ServletOutputStream`. Take a look at the [`PdfServlet`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173) example from the official documentation. In this example, we write the PDF to memory (using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`) and once we've closed the document, we write it to a `ServletOutputStream`: `OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream(); baos.writeTo(os);` There are very specific reasons why you'd want to create the document in memory first and write it to the `ServletOutputStream` once the document is completely finished, but it would lead us too far to explain all those reasons (they're listed in chapter 9 of [my book](http://itextpdf.com/book) and the explanation takes several pages).
2. By default, the *content disposition* is **inline**. This means that the PDF is opened inside the browser in a browser plug-in. If you want the browser to present a "Save as" dialog, you need to change the *content disposition* to **attachment**. This is shown in the [CreateFDF](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=174) example: `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"subscribe.fdf\"");` In this case, we also give a suggestion for the file name. The default name for the file will be `subscribe.fdf`.

**Caveat:** the behavior of the browser can be different, for instance due to specific browser features that make that the browser ignores response headers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this link http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173 . Here, you have used static contents like   document.add(new Paragraph(String.format(
                "You have submitted the following text using the %s method:",
                request.getMethod())));    . But, in my case, I need to display html table contents using table id. Is it possible?

Comment: That's a completely different question. It would require XML Worker: See http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker and http://itextpdf.com/product/xml_worker Please do not abuse the comments of an answer to your question with an extra question. If the answer was correct, accept it. If it wasn't, explain why you think it isn't correct. Your original question didn't mention any HTML table. You were creating a `PdfPTable` populated with data received from a submitted HTML form. Big difference!

Comment: Can you please look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530852/how-to-get-particular-html-table-contents-to-write-it-in-pdf-using-itext   I know you will have answer for my question.

Comment: I don't have the time right now. Also: you *downgraded* instead of *upgrading*. It beats me why you'd want to do that.

Comment: I don't downgrade Bruno. I dont have that much reputation. Please help me!

Comment: I read "Used itextpdf-5.1.0.jar" in your new question. As you previously used itextpdf-5.2.0.jar (in this question), you have downgraded to an older version than the one you were already using. I didn't say anything about down-*voting*.